# Using MemberStack for authentication in a Next.js app with NextAuth.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using MemberStack for authentication in a Next.js app with NextAuth.js. This might not have been my first choice of tools, but I'm migrating from an existing Webflow website that uses MemberStack for auth. I'm starting a new site from a React MUI template that already had Next.JS setup with NextAuth.js examples in place for auth. I wouldn't mind using the same auth provider since at least on the surface, it seems like less work.

MemberStack doesn't appear to have a JavaScript API for logging in that is intended for the backend, they only have the DOM (front-end) package that allows you to login. See: https://developers.memberstack.com/docs/dom-front-end-package#authentication

I'm actually able to get something to work by implementing a custom `CredentialsProvider` in NextAuth.js:

```
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'login',
      name: 'Login',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email', placeholder: 'Enter Email' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password', placeholder: 'Enter Password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          console.log("Logging into memberstack");

          // this hack is needed to make it work
          global.localStorage = {
            setItem: (key, value) => {
              console.log(key);
              console.log(value);
            }
          };

          let loginResult = await memberstack.loginMemberEmailPassword({
            password: credentials?.password,
            email: credentials?.email,
          });
          console.log(loginResult);

          return loginResult?.data;
        } catch (error) {
          // handle error here
          console.error("Error happened");
          console.error(error);
          throw error;
        }
      }
    }),
```

That's all great, except that I have to resort to a hack to implement a `global.localStorage` object since the MemberStack library is writing the loginResponse to localStorage, which of course isn't present on the backend in Node.

So I'm left wondering...

Is there a better way to implement this that isn't a hack? Would I be better off switching to another auth provider that is better supported by NextAuth.js?

I'm open to any and all suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you got any progress on it, Cause it seems that now they have everything available from their React Package (that they've mention is a wrapper for the DOM package) here: https://developers.memberstack.com/docs/react-package

Cause I've been considering using memberstack for my auth, gateing and pricing, but I have no intention to use webflow.

Comment: I did end up using the React package that they provide for the purposes of login/logout. We're mostly using custom forms, so to do the auth to memberstack using the DOM package which the React package will give you access to through the `useMemberstack` hook. For API calls that are made to our backend, we're passing along the JWT that the DOM package saves to localStorage / a cookie as a header in the API call, and then we use the memberstack admin JS package on the backend to validate the JWT before allowing the call to proceed.

Comment: Same here, so far looks like is quite complete. Ive ended up doing the same here